# TypeError: .json WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am getting error when i try to get data from json file at this line in my code `selectedEmployee: employeeList.data.Table[0],`

> TypeError: _employeeList_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.filter is
>   not a function

//App.js

```
    const filterEmployee = (searchText, maxResults) => {
  return employeeList.filter((employee) => {
    if (employee.data.Table.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }).slice(0, maxResults);
}

var maxResults = 4;

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectedEmployee: employeeList.data.Table[0],
            filteredEmployee: filterEmployee('', maxResults)
        }
    }

    onSearch = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            filteredEmployee: filterEmployee(event.target.value, maxResults)
        });
    }

    onEmployeeClick = (employee) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedEmployee: {name: employee.name, info: employee.info, contact: employee.contact}
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Col lg={8} md={7} sm={4} lgOffset={2}>
                <Col lg={6}>
                    <HomePage onSearch={this.onSearch} employeeData={this.state.filteredEmployee} onEmployeeClick={this.onEmployeeClick}/>
                </Col>  
                <Col lg={6}>
                    <EmployeePage selectedEmployee={this.state.selectedEmployee}/>
                </Col>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}
```

//my json file looks like this

```
{
    "data": {
      "Table": [
        {
          "id": "1001",
          "name": "Alez",
          "info": "Alez"
        },
        {
          "id": "1002",
          "name": "Baro",
          "info": "Alez"
        }

      ]
    }
  }
```

What i want to accomplish is using a different .json format.

these was the orginal json file format

```
[
    { 
        "key": "t1",
        "data":{
            "name": "James",
            "info": "Software Development",
            "contact": {
                "office": "781-000-002",
                "mobile": "087-321-0292",
                "sms": "617-000-002",
                "email": "jtaylor@company.ie"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to use these json file format instead and update my code

```
   {
    "data": {
      "Table": [
        {
          "id": "1001",
          "name": "Alez",
          "info": "Alez"
        },
        {
          "id": "1002",
          "name": "Baro",
          "info": "Alez"
        }

      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to the `filter` function call at the top of your code. You can only [`filter` on an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Therefore you need to call filter like using `employeeList.data.Table` as your array:

```
const filterEmployee = (searchText, maxResults) => {
  return employeeList.data.Table.filter((employee) => {
    // returns true if condition is met, otherwise returns false
    return employee.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
  }).slice(0, maxResults);
}
```

and then when checking if the `employee.name` includes the `searchText`, you can just access `employee.name` instead.

Comment: Thank you what about here ` selectedEmployee: employeeList[0].data,` i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: `employeeList` is not an array, therefore you cannot access any items in that variable using `[0]`, that is only for arrays. Instead you could do `employeeList.data.Table[0]` to return the first object in that array, because `employeeList.data.Table` is an array of objects.

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing more code. Feel free to create a new question which might be easier and faster to get your question answered.

Comment: one more thing how can i access name from another page prop?